# Looping through a multidimensional array to output path to files in array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this script which will search a directory and store a file tree to an array below:

```
$dir = ABSPATH."/uploads";
    function getDirectoryTree( $outerDir , $x){
        $dirs = array_diff( scandir( $outerDir ), Array( ".", ".." ) );
        $dir_array = Array();
        foreach( $dirs as $d ){
            if( is_dir($outerDir."/".$d)  ){
                $dir_array[ $d ] = getDirectoryTree( $outerDir."/".$d , $x);
            }else{
                 if (($x)?ereg($x.'$',$d):1)
                    $dir_array[ $d ] = $d;
                }
            }
            return $dir_array;
        }

        $dirlists = getDirectoryTree($dir);

    Array
(
    [2013] => Array
    (
        [adamson] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

            )

        [danaenus] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

            )

        [richardgregson] => Array
            (
                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

            )

        [rik] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

            )

    )

[2014] => Array
    (
        [rik] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tester.pdf] => tester.pdf
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I want everything from the array: data needs to be like "WEBSITENAME.COM/uploads/2013/rik/1/tester.pdf"

I want to loop through the array to retrieve the URL to the file... New working with multidimensional arrays so any guidance would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Which file? Give us example output of `print_r($dirlists)` and point out what you're trying to retrieve from the array.

Comment: please format and indent your code. We love helping, but part of that is you making sure we can easily read it.

Comment: Don3e I want all of the information from the array, I have added a sample in the above of what the output should be.

Comment: I think, given a starting directory, you want a list of all files in that starting directory -- no matter how deep -- expressed as a string path name?  Eg, tree('/a') => array ('/a/1.txt', '/a/b/2.txt').  If so, [does this code from PHP.net work](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#107117)?

Comment: No tried that code, not sure why but it doesn't work, nothing is in the $result[] array

Answer (score 0):

just print the array with var_dump

like

```
var_dump($dirlists);
```

now you should see the structure, when you know the structure you can easily find a way to dig things you need

try this one

```
function getDirectoryTree($outerDir, &$filePaths, $x) {
    $dirs = array_diff(scandir($outerDir), Array(".", ".."));
    $dir_array = Array();
    foreach ($dirs as $d) {
        if (is_dir($outerDir . "/" . $d)) {

            $dir_array[$d] = getDirectoryTree($outerDir . "/" . $d, $filePaths, $x);

        } else {
            if (($x) ? ereg($x . '$', $d) : 1)
                $filePaths[] = $outerDir . "/" . $d;
                $dir_array[$d] = $d;
        }
    }

    return $dir_array;
}
$filePaths = array();
$dirlists = getDirectoryTree($dir, $filePaths);
var_dump(filePaths);
```

Comment: When you say "alot", the hierachy is created on a basis of when the file was uploaded, so the year(which will only be 2 folders for one more year) and the user folders(will only be roughly 20 users) and then 12 folders for the months in each user folder

Comment: after you thrown the var_dump its got more obvious, you should change the getDirectoryTree function to return a list of subdirectories instead of making a new one

Comment: this function is not what I need, it makes it harder to display the data correctly, as I need titles for the year 2013 then the months below that then a link to the file. How can I loop through the array that I originally posted?